# printf in bash with double qouted backslashes

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to get bash printf in doubleqoutes to give me the "right" amount of actually printed backslashes...
Who is escaping who ?
And why does 2 doublequoted backslashes give me 1 printed backslash exactly as 4 doubleqouted backslashes also gives me 1 printed 1 backslash....?
Now 6 doubleqouted backslashes gives me 2 printed backslaches and so does 8 doublquoted backslashes ....??
And so on...
So what/who is escaping what/who in the amount of bash doubleqouted backslashes...

```
povje@povje:~$ which bash
/bin/bash
povje@povje:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Trying to print doublequoted backslashes with printf in bash:

```
povje@povje:~$ printf "\\"
\povje@povje:~$ printf "\\\\"
\povje@povje:~$ printf "\\\\\\"
\\povje@povje:~$ printf "\\\\\\\\"
\\povje@povje:~$ printf "\\\\\\\\\\"
\\\povje@povje:~$
```

so
2*doublequoted \ gives me 1 printed 

4*doubleqouted \ gives me 1 printed 
6*doubleqouted \ gives me 2 printed 

8*doubleqouted \ gives me 2 printed 
10*doubleqouted \ gives me 3 printed 
.
.

so why is every second pair of doubleqouted backslahes ignored ?

Comment: bash is doing something with the backslashes **and** printf uses those backslashes left by bash for its own purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are special in double quotes in bash. You need to escape (i.e. backslash) a backslash in double quotes to get a literal backslash. Use single quotes and you don't need to double backslashes.

Backslashes are also special in printf. You again need to escape (i.e. backslash) a backslash to get it printed.

**But** if there's a backslash followed by a non-special character in the argument of `printf`, the backslash gets interpreted as if escaped, i.e.

```
printf '\'    # prints \
printf '\\'   # prints \ again
printf '\\\'  # prints \\
# ...
```